# How to limit a UITextField for a limited character in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have added delegate UITextFieldDelegate in .h file

Then in .m file under **viewDidLoad**:

```
[self textField:self.comment shouldChangeTextInRange:NSMakeRange(0,10) replacementText:@""];
```

then added the function:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

   if(textField.text.length >= 10)
   {
       return NO;
   }

    return YES;

}
```

My goal is to limit the keyboard input to 10 character for the textfield?? Whats i am doing wrong or how to achieve that ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works correctly with backspace and copy & paste

```
#define MAXLENGTH 10
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSUInteger oldLength = [textField.text length];
    NSUInteger replacementLength = [string length];
    NSUInteger rangeLength = range.length;
    NSUInteger newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength;
    BOOL returnKey = [string rangeOfString: @"\n"].location != NSNotFound;
    return newLength <= MAXLENGTH || returnKey;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to set delegate of UITextField.. and if you want to set for particular  UITextField then you can check in above method like   if(textField == "youtextfield") {  above code }

Answer (score 1):

Remove or comment this line `[self textField:self.comment shouldChangeTextInRange:NSMakeRange(0,10) replacementText:@""];` in `viewDidLoad`.

Add `yourtextfield.delegate = self;` in `viewDidLoad`

and implement below delegate method,

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    //allow back space
    if (range.length == 0 && [string length] == 0) {
        return YES;
    }

    if(textField.text.length >= 10)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else{
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Hope, this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't call the methods "shouldChangeCharactersInRange: explicitly. This delegate method will get called when you type in text in your self.comment TextFiled, provided you have assigned the delegate by saying,

```
self.comment.delegate = self.
```

You can either assigned the delegate in your xib or in the .m file.

Code that you have added in the shouldChangeCharactersInRange method is correct to mask the input to 10 characters.

Hope this will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if(range.length + range.location > textField.text?.characters.count)
    {
        return false
    }

    let newLength = (textField.text?.characters.count)! + string.characters.count - range.length;
    return newLength <= self.maximumCharacterAllowed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if (textField == self.textField)
    {
        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        return (newLength > 10) ? NO : YES;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code

```
#define KMAX_CHAR_LENGTH 20
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField.text.length >= KMAX_CHAR_LENGTH && range.length == 0) {
        return NO; // do not change text
    } else {
        return YES; // Change Text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // Prevent crashing undo bug – see note below.
    if(range.length + range.location > textField.text.length)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return newLength <= 25;
}
```